# Change routing of the controller to include it under another controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, url-routing

I have a controller named **DummyController** when i call the controller it is like `DummyController/Index` i want this controller to be called as `maincontroller/dummycontroller/index` where `mainController` is a different controller altogether.

**Code for DummyController:**

```
  public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View("~/Views/main/dummy/index.cshtml",db.Users.ToList());
            }
```

the location of index file of Dummy Controller is `main/dummy`

Now the problem is when I call the dummy controller's index page i get the url as `dummy/index` i want the url to be displayed as `main/dummy/index`.

Is there any way to create child controllers? o change the url only for the specific controller

Comment: nope..client was happy with a shorter url..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was relatively straightforward, once I got past a simple issue.

By using a combination of `[RoutePrefix("")]` & `[Route("")]` on my controller, I was able to make this work. Attribute Routing requires a call to `routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()` in your Global.asax.cs `RegisterRoutes()` method.

```
    [RoutePrefix("main/dummy")]
    [Route("{action=index}/{id:long?}")]
```

- `{action=index}` defines the action handling for the route, and specifies /index as the default action, if it's not supplied (ie, ~/main/dummy/ will render ~/main/dummy/index
- `{id:long?}` specifies the id route attribute

  - `:long` is the syntax for constraining the param to the `long` datatype
  - `?` denotes this param is optional. ([more on this here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/))

This could also be done using the standard `MapRoute()` technique:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "DummyControllerRoute",
        url: "main/dummy/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Dummy", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

---

I forgot to add what my simple issue was..
I had 2 actions in the controller: `Index()` and `Index(id)`, which would always result in the `AmbiguousRouteException`, and was leading me to believe my Route was defined incorrectly. Changing that to `View(id)` solved it. (I guess technically the route ***was*** wrong, but I didn't need to spend any more time trying to make it work that way)

Comment: No, if this was the case a better approach would have been to create a base controller instead of prefix.

Comment: Sounds like what you were asking for was different than what you actually wanted.. A `MyBaseController` would merely allow the sharing of Actions across Controllers. `AChildController` and `BChildController` would still be accessed via URLS like `/AChild/` and `/BChild/`, respectively. Additionally, as long as `MyBaseController` is not `abstract`, then you could have a 3rd URL  like `/MyBase/`.

Comment: Sub-classing controllers does not inherently enable Routing like that. Logically it makes no sense either: Should each sub-type of a controller be accessible via URL? ie: `~/MyBase/AChild/AChildAction` or `~/MyBase/BChild/BChildAction`. 
This would also put implicit restrictions on the Actions MyBase can contain. A similar analog to this would be `/../../../..` in URLs in the old days that provide unexpected access to a resource that a client shouldn't have access to.

Comment: I can't edit that first comment, but this was assumed, if it was unclear: `class AChildController :  MyBaseController { }` & `class BChildController :  MyBaseController { }`

Comment: Actually i want both the prefix as well as the properties of a controller. This does answer about the url.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by properties of a controller unless creating a base class to share common Actions across controllers (think `Log` actions). All your controllers (`MyBaseController`) would inherit from `System.Web.Mvc.Controller` anyway. Glad I could help :)